# new chromedriver(v2.0.204324.dyu): how to save chromedriver logs into the corresponding file

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Yesterday I updated my old chromedriver(v2.0.204324.dyu) with new one uploaded at https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list
 and now I see all chromedriver logs in the console instead of chromedriver.log file.

the previous version of chromedriver creates chromedriver.log automatically and puts all logs there.

I don't wanna see chromedriver logs in the console.

Any ideas how not to show logs in the console?

Thanks,
Anna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for this was added in Selenium-Webdriver v2.33.0 (see [Issue 3475](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3475)).

You can specify the log path by adding the `service_log_path` option to the browser initialization.

```
#Path and file for the log output
LOG_FILE = 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\chromedriver.log'      

#Start browser with the service_log_path option      
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :service_log_path => LOG_FILE
```